# File Explorer does not work in Windows 10 if started with default folder view (Quick Acces folder)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I backed up several Gb of data over the LAN from my laptop (Dell, Win10) to my PC. I went to drink tea and returned to see the copying process completed. The copying indicator showed 100% completion but for some reason it was impossible to get it shown on the screen. So I right-clicked "close", it asked me "are you sure you want to stop the tranfer?", I clicked Yes, and that's it. File Explorer for some reason stopped working. It shows the left pane with drives, but the main pane is blank, and the sandglass cursor does not change to the normal cursor, just goes on circling.

I restarted the laptop several times. I then disabled the HDD in the BIOS, leaving only the SSD with the system operational. I then run **chkdisk /scan**, which found a couple of mild errors (some files lost by Kaspersky Antivirus) and fixed them. I then run two other tools:

> sfc /scannow
>   dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

and these found no problems at all - so apparently all system files must be in perfect order, mustn't they?

I had to switch to using the FAR manager until I understand what's wrong with File Explorer, wich is still not responding. I launch it, I look at the "waiting" cursor, I wait, then I kill it.

P.S. I've just found that if I open some particular folder, not the default view, File Explorer works. Once I switch to the ***Quick access*** folder, which is the default startup folder, File Explorer hangs.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I disabled **Quick Access** by saving some file from the browser in a folder, then clicking on "See this in File Explorer" option after the file was saved.

This way, File Explorer was launched with a folder view from Quick Access, which was triggering the freeze.

From there, I navigated to the File Explorer settings, and disabled Quick Access and purged all File Explorer history.

I still don't understand why on Earth this problem arose in the first place.